# PHP if-else condition for download csv file

Tags: php, csv, if-statement, shopify

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($t)) {
    $orders               = $sc->call('GET', 'admin/orders.json', array(
        'published_status' => 'published'
    ));
    $myarray              = array();
    $list[]               = array(
 'Name',
        'Email');
    $list                 = array_filter($list);
if ($lineitemcount == 0) {
                array_push($list, array(
                    $order['name'],
                    $order['email']));
$order  = $_GET;
    $list[] = array_to_csv_download($myarray, // this array is going to be the second row
        "numbers.csv");
    $list   = array_filter($list);
    array_to_csv_download($list);
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
}
function array_to_csv_download($list)
{
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach ($list as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
        //print_r($row); die;
    }
    fclose($output);
```

Now my situation is, when click the csv app, it will display download link directly, whether it have orders or not.

I just confused, is it correct my code above or not?

How to fix this?

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: please don't share real info

Comment: how are you get data or value into `$there_are_orders` ?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, but i don't have any other way.

Comment: @ashok_p:I just added. from my above code else part only working.

Comment: @selva : but what you ware saying was you are directly getting download link , which is in 'IF' condition. can you just give me some clarity

Comment: @ashok_p: could you please follow my link?

Comment: ya i have seen it when i click on cvs app it is shoing me unable to connect as it is giving the address of some 'localhost' .

Comment: sorry, when click that csv app, it will display like this, please see the link. http://imgur.com/CznawUQ

Comment: @selva if you give some value to `$there_are_orders` then 'IF' condition will show you the download link

Comment: @ashok_p: Can you explain in code? Thanks

Comment: as i can see in the above code, when you give some value to `$there_are_orders` then `IF` condition will be true and show you the download link or else you will get the else part.

Comment: @ashok:I m new to php, can you edit my code? Thanks

Comment: Yes. According to @ashok_p point, You assigned `$there_are_orders` as `empty`. So it might be go to `else` part only..

Comment: ok to edit the code can you tell me how will you know that you got an "order" ?

Comment: @ashok: I m totaly confused with my code, my question is, when have orders in my shopify store, it will display download link, else will display there is no orders. Did you get my question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code in catalog-generator.php, it may work for you

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Catalog</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page">
<h1>CSV Generator</h1>
<?php

require_once 'lib/shopify.php';
$t="bac2486aa2b31aa5aed1fdd62e77a4ae";
$sc = new ShopifyClient("mine-329.myshopify.com/", $t, API_KEY, SECRET);
 $orders = $sc->call('GET', 'admin/orders.json', array('published_status'=>'published'));

$there_are_orders=count($orders);//count($orders if get you the count of orders)
if($there_are_orders!=0){
    echo '<a href="index-oauth29.php">Download</a>';
} else {
   echo 'There is no orders';
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: :It works. Thanks a lot. I can't think like you :).

Comment: From your code, I got the details as .csv file started from 2nd row. how to start from 1st row? can you help me?

Comment: do you mean the downloaded .cvs file show the data from second row right ?

Comment: :Yes..correct. Thanks :)

Comment: that problem is not with above code that problem may be due to **index-oauth29.php** , once check in it

Comment: yes, but i don't know fix it. can you please help?

Comment: just debug the index-oauth29.php you will get it.     comment the hedders in the that code to see the out put in browser.

Comment: I just edited my index-oauth.php code. Can you tell me where to diagonise the problem?

Comment: If i put comments all the header, it will just print the details without .csv file.

Comment: i know that , now check what is the problem why you are not getting the first 1st row in the browser. if possible take a screen shot and give me to see it

Comment: before edit my catalog-generator.php(i.e,your answer) it will show from 1st row.

Comment: please help me. I just confused.

Comment: this is my screenshot http://imgur.com/q1Vpsz1

Answer (score 1):

As the comments already explain, you are setting `$there_are_orders` to an empty string just before the if statement, so you'll always get "There is no orders".

You first need to determine if there are any orders in the store, and set `$there_are_orders` accordingly. See the [Shopify API documentation for how to get a count of all the orders](http://docs.shopify.com/api/order#count):

> **Count all orders**
>
> ```
> GET /admin/orders/count.json
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> {  
>     "count": 1  
> }
> ```

**EDIT:**

An example:

```
$there_are_orders = $sc->call('GET', 'admin/orders/count.json');

if($there_are_orders) {
    echo '<a href="index-oauth29.php">Download</a>';
} else {
   echo 'There are no orders';
}
```

Comment: @selva No problems, happy to help.

Comment: I have edited my above code?.  This is my index-oauth.php. Can you help, where is the best way to edit this code? Thanks

Comment: If you are already getting `$orders` from `admin/orders.json`, you could just check its size without needing to count the orders again with `/admin/orders/count.json`.

Comment: Could  you  please expalin me with edit my code? I m new to php. Thanks :)

Comment: If there is no orders in my store, it will download .csv file like this, http://imgur.com/kpCYS5N , But what i need is, it will display there is no orders. So where to add your answer in my code? Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: If ashok_p's code works for you, that's great. I would have either checked the size of your existing `$orders` array, or just used `/admin/orders/count.json` rather than fetching all the orders multiple times.

Comment: @selva See my edit above. I haven't tested the example, but it shows the idea.